# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError - incrementing a number and showing the number in view

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

see Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yh8zyr-w4gmmk?devtoolsheight=33&file=app/app.component.ts).

I want to show a live display of `callCount` as `rowCallback()` is getting called as each of the Kendo Grid cells getting checked.

I am expecting the final `callCount` number to be 12 (i.e. 3 rows x 4 cells each = 12).

I am getting the classic `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error. Nothing useful has been mentioned on the Telerik website: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-rowclass

Code for convenience:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { RowClassArgs } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   styles: [`
       .k-grid tr.even { background-color: #f45c42; }
       .k-grid tr.odd { background-color: #41f4df; }
   `],
   template: `
       <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [rowClass]="rowCallback">
       </kendo-grid>
       <div>{{callCount}}</div> <!-- Double bind to show the current number -->
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
   public gridData: any[] = products;
   public callCount: number = 0;

   public rowCallback = (context: any) => {
       this.callCount++; // Incrementing the number
   }
}

const products = [{
   "ProductID": 1,
   "ProductName": "Chai",
   "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
   "Discontinued": true
 }, {
   "ProductID": 2,
   "ProductName": "Chang",
   "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
   "Discontinued": false
 }, {
   "ProductID": 3,
   "ProductName": "Chang",
   "UnitPrice": 28.0000,
   "Discontinued": false
 }
];
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of console error as well ?

Comment: I have added answer to your query and i don't think you should use property binding(rowClass binding) to increment another component property. It is basic rule in angular that component state should not change during property binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are updating view after [AfterViewChecked](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked)

The only solution to your implementation I see is to use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef):

```
export class AppComponent {
   public gridData: any[] = products;
   public callCount: number = 0;

   public rowCallback = (context: any) => {
       this.callCount++; // Incrementing the number
       this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
   }

   constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
}
```

Comment: Error: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: Its because rowCallback is called on every change detection. Let's find a proper solution to your problem. It should not be so tricky. What is your objective with the task?

Answer (score 2):

### The Problem

As the error states, you are setting the value of a property in the view after the Angular Life cycle has ended, (**AfterContentHasBeenChecked**)

Consider this scenario

> You set the value of `callCount = 0`, in your html you have `<div> 0 </div>` 
> The content is checked. 
> The 1st row is loaded 
> Now we update `callCount = 1` and html `<div> 1 </div>` 
> This triggers change detection and hence the error

If we are to implement the above approach we will have to inform anguar of this change for which we can use `ChangeDetectorRef`. Now lets try to implement the above with this

> You set the value of `callCount = 0`, in your html you have `<div> 0 </div>` 
> Trigger change detection
> The content is checked. 
> The 1st row is loaded 
> Now we update `callCount = 1` and html `<div> 1 </div>` 
> Trigger change detection
> The 2nd row is loaded 
> Now we update `callCount = 2` and html `<div> 2 </div>` 
> Trigger change detection
> The 3rd row is loaded 
> Now we update `callCount = 3` and html `<div> 3 </div>` 
> Trigger change detection
> The 1st row is loaded 
> Now we update `callCount = 4` and html `<div> 4 </div>` 
> Trigger change detection
> The 2nd row is loaded 
> Now we update `callCount = 5` and html `<div> 5 </div>` 
> Trigger change detection
> The 3rd row is loaded 
> Now we update `callCount = 6` and html `<div> 6 </div>` 
> Trigger change detection 
> ... 
> This loop will never end and angular will throw error `Maximum stack reached`

The above is what angular is trying to warn you about. It indicates that there is a problem with your approach

### Solution

You will need a way to determine the number of rows **before the content is checked**

The easiest option will be to count the number of products and multiply it with the maximum of the number of properties in each item

```typescript
 import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest,  Observable, of } from "rxjs";
 import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

  // Create a new Observable using Behaviour subject to store current products
  private gridDataSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(products);
  public gridData: Observable<any[]> = this.gridDataSubject$.asObservable();
  
  // Extract the row count being length of the products array
  private rowCount: Observable<number> = this.gridData.pipe(
    map(({ length }) => length)
  );

  // Extract column count being the Maximum of the product with the highest number of properties
  private columCount: Observable<number> = this.gridData.pipe(
    map((data) => data.map(item => Object.keys(item).length)),
    map(data => Math.max(...data))
  );

  // Define to total calls being rows X columns
  public callCount: Observable<number> = combineLatest([this.columCount, this.rowCount]).pipe(map(([row, column]) => row * column))

  public rowCallback = (context: any) => {};
  updateValue() {
    this.gridDataSubject$.next(products2);
  }

  public rowCallback = (context: any) => {};
  updateValue() {
    this.gridDataSubject$.next(products2)
  }
```

In the above code I am using `BehaviorSubject` to store the data as an `Observable`. That way we can use the `piping` and the `map` operator to get the `length` property of the products (which will essentially be the number of rows of the table)

In the html, we can use async pipe to subscribe to this `Observables`

```html
    <button (click)='updateValue()'>Update</button>
    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData | async" [rowClass]="rowCallback">
    </kendo-grid>
    <div>{{ callCount | async }}</div>
    <!-- Double bind to show the current number -->
```

Try clicking on the button, this will update the table and number of rows

[See this Solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yh8zyr-ec1fom)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use the rowClass method to calculate the number of cells in kendo grid.

As specified in the rowClass [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#rowclass), you should use to dynamically set the Css Class name. I think you can easily achieve your purpose using the below methods basic on following scenarios:

- **Case-1:** When you are aware about the number of columns you want to display on the Kendo grid, then you can create a property that will hold it values and use it inside the template expression as follow:

  ```
  import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
  import { RowClassArgs } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';



  @Component({
     selector: 'my-app',
     encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
     styles: [`
         .k-grid tr.even { background-color: #f45c42; }
         .k-grid tr.odd { background-color: #41f4df; }
      `],
     template: `
         <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
         </kendo-grid>
         <div>{{ columnCount * gridData.length }}</div> <!-- Double bind to show the current number-->
       `
  })
   export class AppComponent {
   public gridData: any[] = products;
   public callCount: number = 0;
   public readonly columnCount = 4; // let say grid has 4 column (known prior)
  }

   const products = [{
  "ProductID": 1,
  "ProductName": "Chai",
  "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
  "Discontinued": true
  }, {
   "ProductID": 2,
   "ProductName": "Chang",
   "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
    "Discontinued": false
  }, {
   "ProductID": 3,
   "ProductName": "Chang",
   "UnitPrice": 28.0000,
   "Discontinued": false
  }
  ];
  ```
- **Case-2:** When you are not aware about the number of columns you want to display on the Kendo grid, then you can calculate it dynamically on your component load:

  ```
   import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
   import { RowClassArgs } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';



   @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
      styles: [`
          .k-grid tr.even { background-color: #f45c42; }
          .k-grid tr.odd { background-color: #41f4df; }
       `],
      template: `
          <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
          </kendo-grid>
          <div>{{ columnCount * gridData.length }}</div> <!-- Double bind to show the current number-->
        `
   })
    export class AppComponent {
    public gridData: any[] = products;
    public callCount: number = 0;
    public readonly columnCount = Object.keys(gridData); 
   }

    const products = [{
   "ProductID": 1,
   "ProductName": "Chai",
   "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
   "Discontinued": true
   }, {
    "ProductID": 2,
    "ProductName": "Chang",
    "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
     "Discontinued": false
   }, {
    "ProductID": 3,
    "ProductName": "Chang",
    "UnitPrice": 28.0000,
    "Discontinued": false
   }
   ];
  ```

In any case you can find the column count before rendering the grid and can use it to calculate the grid count.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `setTimeout` callback in your `rowCallback` methods. To avoid `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error.

```
public rowCallback = (context: any) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.callCount++; // Incrementing the number
  });
}
```